# Algorithm for generating all elements of a set consisting of specific $n$-tuples

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, computational-mathematics

I was working on functional analysis last night, and then my mind got distracted by the following problem. Consider a set $$I=\{0,1\}$$Now consider a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ $$X=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_n):x_i\in I \forall i=1..n\}$$
$X$ contains $2^n$ elements, but I'm trying to think of an algorithm that can generate all the elements of $X$. I'm not looking for any computer code but just the general form such an algorithm would take. Is there such an algorithm that could be implemented by a computational device?

Comment: Yes, there is -- you are basically asking if there is a computational model (e.g., Turing machine) that can generate all numbers between $0$ and $2^{n-1}$ (in binary); e.g., that can implement a counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I tackle this problem with school kids I want to lead them to the recursive algorithm that says, essentially, that after you've listed the subsets for some value of $n$ you can list those for $n+1$ by adding first $0$ and then $1$ to the subsets you have for $n$.

Several bonus observations:

- you've listed and counted the vertices of the cube in each dimension.
- if you prefix rather than append the new bit you've written all the numbers from $0$ to $2^{n}-1$ in base 2, in order.

Comment: Ok I thought as much. Would such an algorithm hog lots of memory though as for each step you'd have to keep all subsets from the previous step in the memory?

Comment: You code each subset as a bitstring, so the memory to store all the subsets is just the memory needed to store the numbers less than $2^n$. Since the computer "knows"  those numbers you don't even need to compute or store them. To find the $k$th subset just write out $k$ in base 2 - easy in most languages - and see where the 1s are.

Comment: That is rather clever. This is where I wish I had taken CS instead of chemistry as 1st year elective, would have been far more useful and interesting. Thanks for the nice explanation.

Comment: First year CS would probably be programming of some kind. What you want is discrete mathematics, preferably taught to a class with both math and cs students so the syllabus must address both views of the subject. For example: http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/320/ .

Comment: I did a discrete mathematics course but it was heavily biased towards the mathematical side of things. Binary representations were not mentioned and the algorithms were few and far between.